# Display issue when using toolbar buttons after setting initial camera position in a 3D matlab figure

Tags: matlab, camera, rotation, zooming

I have some strange display issue after setting the initial camera position in a matlab figure.

I mean data, camera position and target are all fine at the very beginning but if I **first** use the zoom button, then the **rotate3D** button, then the displayed data suddenly become very small (I need to zoom again to get normal behavior and indifferently use zoom/rotate in any order). NB: I have no issue if I first rotate, then zoom.

**First zoom**

[image: zoom]

**Then rotate 3D**

*The data sphere abruptly becomes very small*

[image: rotate3D]

Am I doing something wrong or is it just a bug?

Here is my code for testing:

```
function [] = TestCamera()
%[
    % Define dummy data on a sphere
    azimuths = linspace(0, 359, 360) * pi/180;
    elevations = linspace(0,180, 181) * pi/180;
    [A,E]  = ndgrid(azimuths, elevations);
    X = cos(A) .* sin(E);
    Y = sin(A) .* sin(E);
    Z = cos(E);
    Data = peaks(cos(A), sin(E));

    % Create figure/axes + set initial camera position
    figure(1);
    clf;    
    axes('Visible', 'off', 'DataAspectRatio', [1 1 1], ...
         'CameraPosition', [1 1 1], 'CameraTarget', [0 0 0]);

    % Add graphics
    hold on;

    d = 1.7; t = d + 0.1;
    quiver3(0,0,0, d,0,0, 'LineWidth', 2, 'Color', 'r'); text(t, 0, 0, 'x', 'FontWeight', 'bold', 'Color', 'r');
    quiver3(0,0,0, 0,d,0, 'LineWidth', 2, 'Color', 'g'); text(0, t, 0, 'y', 'FontWeight', 'bold', 'Color', 'g');
    quiver3(0,0,0, 0,0,d, 'LineWidth', 2, 'Color', 'b'); text(0, 0, t, 'z', 'FontWeight', 'bold', 'Color', 'b');

    surf(X, Y, Z, Data); shading flat

    hold off;
%]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! The camera was too close from the object. Placing the camera further in distance solved the issue:

```
axes(..., 'CameraPosition', [10 10 10], 'CameraTarget', [0 0 0], 'CameraViewAngle', 10, ...);
...
xlim([-1 1]); ylim([-1 1]); zlim([-1 1]);
```

Here is full corrected sample code:

```
function [] = TestCamera()
%[
    % Define dummy data on a sphere
    azimuths = linspace(0, 359, 360) * pi/180;
    elevations = linspace(0,180, 181) * pi/180;
    [A,E]  = ndgrid(azimuths, elevations);
    X = cos(A) .* sin(E);
    Y = sin(A) .* sin(E);
    Z = cos(E);
    Data = peaks(cos(A), sin(E));

    % Create figure/axes + set initial camera position
    figure(1);
    clf;    
    axes('Visible', 'off', 'DataAspectRatio', [1 1 1], ...
         'CameraPosition', [10 10 10], 'CameraTarget', [0 0 0], 'CameraViewAngle', 10);

    % Add graphics
    hold on;

    d = 1.7; t = d + 0.1;
    quiver3(0,0,0, d,0,0, 'LineWidth', 2, 'Color', 'r'); text(t, 0, 0, 'x', 'FontWeight', 'bold', 'Color', 'r');
    quiver3(0,0,0, 0,d,0, 'LineWidth', 2, 'Color', 'g'); text(0, t, 0, 'y', 'FontWeight', 'bold', 'Color', 'g');
    quiver3(0,0,0, 0,0,d, 'LineWidth', 2, 'Color', 'b'); text(0, 0, t, 'z', 'FontWeight', 'bold', 'Color', 'b');

    surf(X, Y, Z, Data); shading flat

    hold off;

    xlim([-1 1]);
    ylim([-1 1]);
    zlim([-1 1]);  
%]
```